# make a trail renderer without built in trail renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to make a trail follow a game object with c# code without using the built in trail renderer and so does anyone have the code that would do this.

Thanking You

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is your goal, what are your limitations (that make you unable to use built-in trail renderer) and what have you tried already.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few examples you can use on the [Unity Wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Scripts/Effects) page. All of them are written in C# and include some documentation.